# JAVA Executing stack of threads by n

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

maybe someone could recommend some good examples concerning thread executions, thread management. Maybe not only examples but article, tutorial if you will with examples.

Generally I have a problem where I need to download a bunch of files from the web, but connection is limited to two. So when I gather up all the url's to files I need, I'd like to download say... 100 files but do so in async manner by two until all the threads finish their job.

Thank, you for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that uses a [fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) of size 2, and [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) all the tasks to that `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 2):

An [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) should take care of thread management for you.

```
final int POOL_SIZE = 2;
final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
```

you can then call the [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to execute runnable tasks

Answer (score 2):

I think ThreadPoolExecutor should help you, there many various implementations of such polling in java.util.concurrent.*;

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an article, but I do know of a good book that covers general multi-threaded programming using Java. It is called [Java Concurrency in Practice.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) It does cover general usage patterns, etc.